# Nested For Loop printout over different ranges

Tags: vba, excel, loops

The code should be displaying five different values based off the 'Con' value for each value in 'Eth'. The values in 'Con' and 'Eth' change filter values in a pivot table. Currently the code is going through all 7 'Eth' values and placing the final set of values (7) in all cells. This is the current output from the below code.[Pivot Table manipulated by code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfNB9.png)

[image: Code Output]

**I'd like the values of 0-4 to be unique for each 'Option' 1-7.**

Here is my current code,

```
Sub Math()

Dim subject As String
Dim Shift As Variant
subject = "Math"
Sheets("Pivot").Range("B6") = subject
Sheets("Pivot").Range("G5") = subject

For Each Eth In Range("AL3:AL9")
For Five = 0 To 34 Step 5
            Set Shift = Range("B5").Offset(0, Five)
            Set Shft = Range("B7").Offset(0, Five)
    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
Sheets("Pivot").Range("B4") = Eth
    For Each Con In Range("AM3:AM7")
        Sheets("Pivot").Range("B5") = Con
    x = Sheets("Pivot").Range("D2").Value
        Shift.Offset(0, Con).Value = x
    y = Sheets("Pivot").Range("D3").Value
        Shft.Offset(0, Con).Value = y

    Next Con

 Next Five
Next Eth

End Sub
```

Comment: you'll need to provide a sample spreadsheet of your data, or at least explain how the code relates to the sample spreadsheet you did provide - or be more clear in your question. If you could tell us what line or range of code is not doing what you expect, that may help as well.

Comment: I uploaded what I was allowed to. The line of code that is not working as intended, I believe, is, For Each Con In Range - > Next Con

Comment: does each cell in `Eth` and `Con` have a value that defines the `offset` column?

Comment: can you provide the screenshots of what `Range("AL3:AL9")` and `Range("AM3:AM7") refer to (or are these just ranges that have the unique values for ethnicity and whatever con stands for?

Comment: That's correct just unique values for Eth & Con. Con is 0-4, and Eth is American Indian, African American, Asian American, etc. The embed picture shows the values as well. "Option 1-7" are the values for `Range("AL3:AL9")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have an extra loop that in `For Five = 0 to 34 Step 5` that is causing each iteration to be written to all sets of cells every time.

Try this:

```
Sub Math()

Dim subject As String, Shift As Range, Shft As Range

subject = "Math"

Sheets("Pivot").Range("B6") = subject
Sheets("Pivot").Range("G5") = subject

Dim Five As Long
Five = 0

For Each Eth In Range("AL3:AL9")

    Sheets("Pivot").Range("B4") = Eth
    Set Shift = Range("B5").Offset(0, Five)
    Set Shft = Range("B7").Offset(0, Five)

    Dim x As Double, y As Double

    For Each Con In Range("AM3:AM7")

        Sheets("Pivot").Range("B5") = Con
        x = Sheets("Pivot").Range("D2").Value
        Shift.Offset(0, Con).Value = x

        y = Sheets("Pivot").Range("D3").Value
        Shft.Offset(0, Con).Value = y

    Next Con

    Five = Five + 5

Next Eth

End Sub
```